# How to add value in a column in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

I've one Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'a': [1,2,3,None,4,None,2,4,5,None]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

     a
 0  1.0
 1  2.0
 2  3.0
 3  NaN
 4  4.0
 5  NaN
 6  2.0
 7  4.0
 8  5.0
 9  NaN
```

i want to add the value till NaN comes, Once it will get the NaN then it will stop and start from the starting.

```
     a    b
0  1.0    6
1  2.0    6
2  3.0    6
3  NaN  NaN
4  4.0    4
5  NaN  NaN
6  2.0   11
7  4.0   11
8  5.0   11
9  NaN  NaN
```

how can i achive this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Using `cumsum` create the `groupby` key then `transform` with `mask`

```
df.a.groupby(df.a.isnull().cumsum()).transform('sum').mask(df.a.isnull())
0     6.0
1     6.0
2     6.0
3     NaN
4     4.0
5     NaN
6    11.0
7    11.0
8    11.0
9     NaN
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Comment: perfect way to go here.